# Differentiate between array types in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

### TL;DR

```js
function foo(x: string[] | number[]) {

    // HOW TO DETERMINE WHETHER x IS OF TYPE string[] OR number[]?

}
```

### Full Story

I have a class `X` which can be instantiated with either no args or an array of string or an array of number:

```js
class X {

    constructor(...args?: string[] | number[]) {

        // ensure there are args and array isn't empty
        if (!args || args.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        // check for number[]
        if (typeof args[0] === 'number') { // <<<< THIS IS WHERE I'M LOOKING FOR A DIFFERENT SOLUTION
            this.setNumbers(...args); // <<<< THE ERROR

        }
        // it's a string[]
        else {
            this.setStrings(...args);
        }
    }

    function setNumbers(...args: number[]): X {
        // TODO: validate and set numbers
        return this;
    }

    function setStrings(...args: string[]): X {
        // TODO: validate and set strings
        return this;
    }
}
```

I couldn't find a solution on how to determine the type of the `args` array, other than checking the type of the actual content.

And logically speaking this would be a valid solution: The `args` array can only ever be either of type `string[]` or `number[]`. It can never be a mix of both types (like a `(string | number)[]` would allow it to be).
So if it's non-empty and has an element of type `number`, then it has to be of type `number[]`, but TypeScript doesn't agree with me on that:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

#### Ideas to a Solution

It would be nice if we could check `if (args instanceof number[])`, but that won't work on primitive data types, because they can't be instantiated and what gets instantiated here is an *array* of a certain type (not the type itself) and TypeScript kinda agrees: `TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

So how about `if (args instanceof Array<number>)`? Would be nice as well, but `TS2359: The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.`.

**What would be the correct way to check the type of the `args` array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no runtime information on the Array itself, so checking the content is a good approach. You need to use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to convince the compiler that your check narrows the type for the entire array:

```
class X {

    constructor(...args: string[] | number[]) {

        // ensure there are arguments and array isn't empty
        if (!args || args.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        // check for number[]
        if (this.isNumberArray(arguments[0])) { 
            this.setNumbers(...arguments);

        }
        // it's a string[]
        else {
            this.setStrings(...arguments);
        }
    }

    isNumberArray(args: string[] | number[]): args is number[] {
      return typeof arguments[0] === 'number';
    }

    setNumbers(...args: number[]): X {
        // TODO: validate and set numbers
        return this;
    }

    setStrings(...args: string[]): X {
        // TODO: validate and set strings
        return this;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQTpusA9gOwgFwCcBXYPTAgCgDoawCBzCALmnwIEtt6BtAXWgA%200bEQC2AIwCmBPgEpEKdEugB6FdEm4iBSdDwALabrrGGYzXhhhsAE2h0CYAJ7R2EbAHI8G0QAc8TqjKaOwAZtAUAIR0jIJCMRBUIJr0BtAAvJnQAAzyyMHBOnja2ADcQcEAvooFahiGwADW0KHkwmJSMrwVymERBm5UbgByHdIAggSOThQx5tiW3Nm8snnQPQV6%20oMQknijEtIQ1LRmohYQsuUb6NWbdex4HlashJw83ZuSILsKm0oDRK7PAAZTeXGONCoc3OC0u5U2d1uNRCEAOnUm01mDGYrw4XD4gnahy6shYCVcMBEJMJ%20WURRKeicvkkmHCMIuS34mXS0A81M6HgRyJ6wPRRxO0JxLAF0jkLHgdOCdQAKgB5AAiapYADcwCB2DYwHhjLZWHtiZ0IDc0AyCNgtm5hWhqqK9mD8YxJQkWGx3vK4H9aup1VrdfrDcbTXZgXj3tbNnaHYDndBqpUgA)

On top of that:

The fact that [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object is used for functions with variable number of parameters in ES3 & ES5 should not make you use it in typescript.

For functions with variable number of parameters in typescript, you should use [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters). Typescript compiler will compile it to:

- [Js rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) with ES2015 target
- arguments object with ES3 or ES5 target

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for! You are right, I shouldn't have used `arguments` and in my actual code I don't. I've edited my question and replaced `arguments` with `args` to not confuse other. Regarding rest parameters: I'm using those in my code, am I not?

Comment: You are, but the compiler gets confused with `arguments` param name. Simple rename to args did the job